# Workspace won't appear in aptana

Tags: workspace, aptana3

I am using Aptana Studio 3 3.6.0.201407100658, and for some reason my workspace folder will not show up in the file explorer. Does anyone know how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try File > Switch Workspace > Other… to select the right workspace.